# Using induction to show that a set of equations solve a set of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, induction

I want to show that the set of differential equations $$p_n'(t)=-n\lambda p_n(t)+(n-1)\lambda p_{n-1}(t) \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$$
Is satisfied by $$p_n(t)=e^{-\lambda t}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{n-1}$$
I would like to show this without simply differentiating the solution. I think induction on the natural numbers seems reasonable. I think a good place to start is to notice that $p_n =(1-e^{-\lambda t})p_{n-1}$ seems to be a pattern that fits the equations.

*Proof:*
Base case: We can use the method of integrating factors to straightforwardly calculate $p_2(t)$ and $p_3(t)$ $$p_2(t)=e^{-\lambda t}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^1 $$ $$p_3(t)=e^{-\lambda t}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^2=(1-e^{-\lambda t})p_2(t) $$
so the base case is true.

Inductive hypothesis: We now assume that $p_n =(1-e^{-\lambda t})p_{n-1}$ is true.

Then $p_n (1-e^{-\lambda t}) = (1-e^{-\lambda t})(1-e^{-\lambda t})p_{n-1}$ by the inductive hypothesis.
Now $$p_{n+1} = (1-e^{-\lambda t})p_n $$
End of proof.

Now, I haven't used induction in a long time and somehow I feel this proof is incomplete. Can anyone offer some guidance?

Comment: How did you conclude $p_{n+1} = (1-e^{-\lambda t}) p_n$? Did you use the differential equation?

Comment: @RobertIsrael This is the crux of my problem I suspected I couldn't simply conclude that. Any idea how to complete the proof after the inductive hypothesis?

Comment: Hint: What do you get by substituting $p_{n} = (1-e^{-\lambda t}) p_{n-1}$ into the differential equation?